# compare two unsigned number and in gate level

Tags: verilog

I have learned verilog a few days ago.

I have figure about it but have no idea how to know which is larger when comparing two unsigned 4-bits numbers in gate level.

Could you give me some hint about the algorithm?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the two nubers be **a** and **b** defined by the bits a1..a4 and b1..b4 like shown below:

```
a= a1*8+a2*4+a3*2+a1  
b= b1*8+b2*4+b3*2+b1
```

The Result:

```
c  result (c==true iff a>b)
```

The logic formula for c:  ( *&* means *and*, *|* means *or*, *!* means *not*)

```
c=(a1 & !b1)  | 
  (!(a1 xor b1) & (a2 & !b2)) |
  (!(a1 xor b1) & (!(a2 xor b2)  (a3 & !b3)) |
  (!(a1 xor b1) & (!(a2 xor b2)  & (!(a3 xor b3)  (a4 & !b4))
```

[This does not check for equality only shows if a>b]

Explanation of the parts of the formula:

if highest bit of a is set but not the highest bit of b, => `a>b`
    `(a1 & !b1)`

if highest bit is the same but second highest bit of a is set but not second higest bit of b => `a>b`
    `(!(a1 xor b1) & (a2 & !b2))`

if the two highest bit are equals but third highest of a is set but not third highest of b  => `a>b`
    `(!(a1 xor b1) & (!(a2 xor b2)  (a3 & !b3))`

if highest three bits are equals but lowest bit of a is set but lowest bit of b isn't =>  `a>b`
    `(!(a1 xor b1) & (!(a2 xor b2)  & (!(a3 xor b3)`

---

P.s
For such little numbers you can also use a ROM with 8bits address and one bit output which contains the answers for all possible values of a and b.